# StackOverflow by Scala Compiler

Tags: scala, compiler-errors

Scala compiler (2.11.8) throws StackOverflowException:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeMaps$TypeMap.mapOver(TypeMaps.scala:109)
at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeMaps$ForEachTypeTraverser.traverse(TypeMaps.scala:1052)
at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeMaps$TypeTraverser.apply(TypeMaps.scala:300)
at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeMaps$TypeMap.mapOver(TypeMaps.scala:110)
at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeMaps$ForEachTypeTraverser.traverse(TypeMaps.scala:1052)
at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeMaps$TypeTraverser.apply(TypeMaps.scala:300)
at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeMaps$TypeMap.mapOver(TypeMaps.scala:175)
at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeMaps$ForEachTypeTraverser.traverse(TypeMaps.scala:1052)
at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeMaps$TypeTraverser.apply(TypeMaps.scala:300)
at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeMaps$TypeTraverser.apply(TypeMaps.scala:298)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.loop$1(List.scala:173)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.mapConserve(List.scala:189)
at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeMaps$TypeMap.mapOver(TypeMaps.scala:115)
at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeMaps$ForEachTypeTraverser.traverse(TypeMaps.scala:1052)
at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeMaps$TypeTraverser.apply(TypeMaps.scala:300)
at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeMaps$TypeMap.mapOver(TypeMaps.scala:175)
at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeMaps$ForEachTypeTraverser.traverse(TypeMaps.scala:1052)
at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeMaps$TypeTraverser.apply(TypeMaps.scala:300)
at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeMaps$TypeTraverser.apply(TypeMaps.scala:298)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.loop$1(List.scala:173)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.mapConserve(List.scala:189)
at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeMaps$TypeMap.mapOver(TypeMaps.scala:115)
```

From observing the mapOver function code, it seems the problem not in recursive implicits, but in type variance. As a lot of code has been changed since last successful compilation, I don't have an idea what is broken though, and cant' extract more info from the compiler (with "-verbose", "-Ylog:icode", "-Ydebug", "-Ytyper-debug" flags). Any idea what it might be about?

Comment: What did you to that causes this exception? Are you trying to compile some code that you wrote? Post that code.

Comment: The compiler hangs with all the "sbt compile" and internal/external compilation in Intellij Idea. The code is more than 5K lines of code, and significantly changed since last successful compilation, so it is not easy to find a concrete place by including/excluding parts of it.

Comment: You could show the top of the stack, and also what compiler phase bombed by `-verbose` for scalac. Looks like it's recursing through an upper type bound.

Comment: cf https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9142